# Как переименовать папку в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, rename

Как переименовать нужную мне папку в python по нужной директории?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import os

os.rename("olddir","newdir")
```

Answer (score 4):

`QFileSystemModel.setReadOnly(enable)` 
параметры:  enable – QtCore.bool

Если для этого свойства установлено значение `False`, модель каталога позволит переименовывать, копировать и удалять файлы и каталоги. По умолчанию это свойство `True`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTreeView, QFileSystemModel, QApplication 
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QDir

class Tree(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        QTreeView.__init__(self)
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
        self.setModel(model)
        self.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir.currentPath()))
        model.setReadOnly(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Tree()       
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Воу, крутая вещь надо попробовать :)

Comment: интересно, но не по теме вопроса :)